# C++/V8 Convenient way to call a non-static function / creating temporary instance

Tags: c++, v8, temporary-objects

I'm looking for a way to turn this (which works):

```
HandleScope scope;
scope.Close(stuff);
```

Into *something* like this:

```
(HandleScope scope).Close(stuff);
```

I tried with:

```
HandleScope::Close(stuff);
```

But it doesn't work.

[@Xeo]

It's this class from V8.

http://bespin.cz/~ondras/html/classv8_1_1HandleScope.html

---

If you dowvote, at least explain why you're doing it.

Comment: What does the declaration of `static_fn` look like?

Comment: If `MyClass::static_fn();` did not work, there is a problem with the declaration.

Comment: @almosnow Which of the static functions did you call, and what does the function call look like? Equally important: What error message did you get?

Comment: @jogojapan Close(), I've just updated my question with the code :D

Comment: The `Close()` function isn't static. You must create an instance before you can call it, unfortunately.

Comment: Generally speaking, what you can do is to create a temporary instance "on the fly" and call the function on that: `HandleScope().Close(stuff);`. (You might have to add arguments in the constructor call.) But I am not sure if a temporary can be used in this context (i.e. with instances of those `v8` classes).

Comment: @jogojapan, Ok thanks, I thought that you would only create an instance when using the 'new' keyword. Is there a way to perform the same stuff but in one line?

Comment: @jogojapan dude you rock, that totally works, thanks a lot!

Comment: @almosnow Syntactically it works, but whether this is a correct usage of this specific class, I don't know. I'd need to read the documentation more carefully. Calling a close function on a temporary sounds like a strange thing to do, but then, I don't really know much about v8.

Comment: @jogojapan how are you calling a constructor without memory allocated to it?

Comment: @littleadv I don't understand your question. `HandleScope()` creates a temporary object on the stack. Memory is allocated on the stack.

Answer (score 3):

This can only be done with constructors. Variable declaration and function call are both statements. Why would you do that? You pay per `;` in your code?

As @Adam points out, if the function is static, you can call it directly, but then you don't need to create an instance of the class at all.

Answer (score 3):

If the function is static, I think you can just call `MyClass::static_fn();`

Comment: It turned out the function wasn't static after all (although the questioner originally thought it was).

Answer (score 1):

If I correct in guessing that `Close` is a non-static method, then the proper syntax for what you wish is

```
HandleScope().Close(stuff);
```

A temporary instance of `HandleScope` is created, `Close` is called on it, and the temporary is immediately destroyed.